# Assign class function pointer to class structure member

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have this class:

```
class Test
{
    public:
        int fnc(int a) {
        return a + 1;
    };
    struct {
        int(*fp)(int a);
    } s;
    void assign() { s.fp = &(this->fnc); } // <-- error here
};
```

But i get a compile error (VS2017). The error is:

> *Error    C2276   '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression*

I also tried without the '&', but that just warns me that i need to include it.
Is it not possible to do this?

A note: This is a reduced example that illustrates the problem. In this case, i can't change the pointer type in the struct, since the struct need to be passed to a 3rd party function that resides in a .lib file that is written in C. What i want is to make the 3rd party lib call my provided function that resides in the class.

Comment: A lot of C callback APIs ask you to provide a `void*` argument that will be given to your callback function. If this is the case, pass `this` as the generic argument and write a `static` or free wrapper function that takes that `void*` and casts it back to actual `this` type. If the API only takes a function pointer, then you are very limited in what you can do. There is no way to communicate an instance on which to call your function.

Comment: Thanks Francois. Found this link in the duplicate: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr
Good reading if you want to understand more. Certainly helped me out.